# Wheh building android platform code system hangs

Tags: android, build, platform

Am trying to build AOSP code. Following the instruction am able to start the build but after few minutes my system hangs .System has 3GB RAM and 320GB hdd.

Comment: Building with only 3GB RAM will take you a *long* time. It might not even complete building. Leave it for a few hours (preferably overnight) and see if it helps.

Comment: I donno what magic I did, its building without much effort :).
Now what ? I have got many .img files ..How will i put this onto a device? Should i raise a new question for this?)

Comment: Install fastboot drivers if you are using Microsoft Windows. What target device did you build for? You should go through source.android.com for steps to build and flash android image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a 3GB RAM ubuntu system and AOSP source compiles without problems. Try using

```
make -j4
```

This will spawn 4 threads and will compile faster on a multi-core CPU.

Comment: which latest release did u try ? and how much time does it take?Do i need to do any linux settings?Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

it will not compile ..requires about 6 gig ram or more..trust me I use to build on 3gig machines sometime ago.. stop doing it about 1.5 years ago due changing requirements of needed ram.

The good news is that most economy machines you see in walmart now for about $300 to $500 can in fact build AOSP code even though they may have only 8 12 gig ram.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try to upgrade my system.Build is going on now.I hope it will finish before next version of android releases :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need additional RAM to compile AOSP code. Although it may build with 6 GB, I recommend at least 8 GB; without the extra gigabytes, bad things could happen.